# Debug stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I wish to set a breakpoint in a stored procedure in SSMS and have it triggered (to start debugging) when the procedure is invoked from my external application. Is this feasible? If so, how can I set it up?

Comment: You can watch, what is the output of the procedure using SQL Profiler (with usage of old way - print messages as debug), or here is a post that should meet your needs: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267868/sql-server-debug-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

Comment: You can also check with print statement in sql server procedure to check how your procedure is behaving.

Comment: If you want to debug a stored procedure from Visual Studio:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885855/how-to-debug-stored-procedure-
in-vs-2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. You can debug only your execution of stored procedures, either in [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/transact-sql-debugger?view=sql-server-2017) (excluding the most recent v.18, because debugging has been removed) or in [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but you cannot attach to someone else's session.

You can modify the stored procedure to dump debugging information to a log table and check the log after the execution. You can also monitor another session via [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) or [Trace/Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017).

One side note - debugging in production is not recommended. For example, while your code is stopped, it will hold locks, which can cause blocking issues.